# Getting Result from JQuery Based On List Item

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

after getting the list id from navigation, i have to send the id to php file that returns JSON list.

This is my jquery syntax

```
$("#ul_navigation li").click(function(e) {
        idsec = this.id;
        alert(idsec);
        $.getJSON("spage.php", { ids : idsec }, function(data,result){
            $("#divPage").show("slow");
            $('#divPage').append(result.content[0].title)
                         .append(result.content[0].full_text);
        }, JSON); 
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
```

and place it into div id called divpage.

Here's my spage.php syntax

```
<?php
//get necessary file associate
include_once 'configuration.php';
$q = mysql_real_escape_string(($_GET['ids']));
$sql = "SELECT title, full_text FROM ** WHERE id =" . $q;
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$title_array = array();
$cname = array();

while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $cname['title'] = html_entity_decode($r['title']);
    $cname['full_text'] = html_entity_decode($r['full_text']);

    array_push($title_array, $cname);
}

echo '{"content":' . json_encode($title_array) . '}';
?>
```

This return JSON array like :

`{"content":[{"title":"Test Post 900","full_text":"Full Text"}]}`

But it's not working. Any suggestion?

**UPDATE**

after showing the result on id, if i want to store the result in html component how to do that? (example, title is placed on `<h2>` and the text result is in `<p>`)

this is the html syntax

```
   <div id="divPage" style="display: none;">
                <h2 id="divPage_header"></h2>
                <p id ="divPage_content"></p>
   </div>
```

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to quote that JSON parameter :

```
$("#ul_navigation li").on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $.getJSON("spage.php", { ids : this.id }, function(result){

        var p  = $('<p />',  {text: result.content[0].title}),
            h2 = $('<h2 />', {text: result.content[0].full_text});

        $("#divPage").show("slow").append(h2, p);
    }, 'JSON');  // missing quotes
});
```

And in the PHP, stay away from the deprecated `mysql_*` functions, as they are not secure.
And don't echo like this :

```
echo '{"content":'.json_encode($title_array).'}';
```

do :

```
$json = array('content' => $title_array);
echo json_encode($title_array);
```

to make sure whatever you echo is valid

Comment: thanks for your answer, i just replaced the echo '{"content":'.json_encode($title_array).'}'; to your suggestion but, the result is different. where am i missing? secondly, if i want to place the result in specific html tags, how to do that? (update2)

Comment: If the first echo works for you, use that, I just like echoing the encoded JSON directly to avoid errors, but if there are no errors, there is no reason to change it really. As for the HTML elements, I'll edit the javascript.

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter to the success callback function is the `data` of the request

```
$("#ul_navigation li").click(function(e) {
    idsec = this.id;
    alert(idsec);
    $.getJSON("spage.php", { ids : idsec }, function(data){
        $("#divPage").show("slow");
        $('#divPage').append(data.content[0].title)
        .append(data.content[0].full_text);
    }, JSON); 
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#ul_navigation li").click(function(e) {
    idsec = this.id;
    alert(idsec);
    $.getJSON("spage.php", { ids : idsec }, function(result){
        $("#divPage").show("slow");
        var appendHTML = '<div id="divPage">'+
                           '<h2 id="divPage_header">'+result.content[0].title+'</h2>'+
                           '<p id ="divPage_content">'+result.content[0].full_text+'</p>'+
                           '</div>';
        $('#divPage').append(appendHTML);
    }, JSON); 
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```